Whole Home Filtration vs Hydroviv
We are getting ready to submit our private well water for testing. We know the water is hard, so we already have a sediment filter & a water softener. We also did a bacteria test and that came back negative. I could give these test results to Hydroviv and receive a custom filter for several POU systems around the house, but wouldn't it make more sense for us to just get a Whole Home Filtration system and choose the filters based on the test results? These would likely be a sediment, activated carbon, and MAYBE kinetic degradation fluxion (but probably just the first 2...) filters. If we really want several POU systems, wouldn't it make sense to make those be a RO system for finer filtration for drinking and cooking like for our kitchen faucet, ice maker, and bar faucet?
Can someone tell me what would be the advantage of going with Hydroviv in this scenario? I can't really think of one other than a whole home filtration system tends to waste more water and maybe go through filters faster. Thoughts?

So evaluate the water used from each faucet and plan accordingly for your use.

As I mentioned, I think only the kitchen faucet, ice maker, and maybe bar faucet really needs "special attention" for drinking and cooking (our refrigerator doesn't have water or ice).  Is there an advantage to having the whole home ACB and KDF (if we have heavy metals) for bathing & brushing teeth?

I imagine it depends on usage.  A whole house filter gets used for all water that passes through it.  Generally filters are going need to be changed based on the volume of water that runs through them so your whole house filter is going to need to be changed way more often then POU filters but certainly more convenient to just have the one.
